# Data Science: Scoring methodology

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, data-science, scoring

I am looking for any methodology to assign a risk score to an individual based on certain events. I am looking to have a 0-100 scale with an exponential assignment. For example, for one event a day the score may rise to 25, for 2 it may rise to 50-60 and for 3-4 events a day the score for the day would be 100.

I tried to Google it but since I am not aware of the right terminology, I am landing up on random topics. :(

Is there any mathematical terminology for this kind of scoring system? what are the most common methods you might know?

P.S.: Expert/experience data scientist advice highly appreciated ;)

Comment: It's a simple exponential function.  however, what you've described is too inexact to suggest anything in particular.  The points (1, 25), (2, 50), (4, 100) are linear; change the last ordinal to 3, and it's a trivial exponential function.  Tighten your requirements, and we can give you an answer, or you can easily derive one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start by writing some qualifications:

1. 0 events trigger a score of 0.
2. Non edge event count observations are where the score – 100-threshold would live.
3. Any score after the threshold will be 100.

If so, here's a (very) simplified example:

#### Stage Data:

```
userid <- c("a1","a2","a3","a4","a11","a12","a13","a14","u2","wtf42","ub40","foo","bar","baz","blue","bop","bob","boop","beep","mee","r")
events <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,2,3,6,122,13,1)
df1 <- data.frame(userid,events)
```

#### Optional: Normalize events to be in (1,2].

This might be helpful for logarithmic properties. (Otherwise, given the assumed function, score=events^exp, as in this example, 1 event will always yield a score of 1) This will allow you to control sensitivity, but it must be done right as we are dealing with exponents and logarithms. I am not using normalization in the example:

```
normevents <- (events-mean(events))/((max(events)-min(events))*2)+1.5
```

Set the quantile threshold for max score:

```
MaxScoreThreshold <- 0.25
```

#### Get the non edge quintiles of the events distribution:

```
qts <- quantile(events[events>min(events) & events<max(events)], c(seq(from=0, to=100,by=5)/100))
```

#### Find the Events quantity that give a score of 100 using the set threshold.

```
MaxScoreEvents <- quantile(qts,MaxScoreThreshold)
```

#### Find the exponent of your exponential function

Given that:

1. Score = events ^ exponent
2. events is a Natural number - integer >0: We took care of it by
   omitting the edges)
3. exponent > 1

Exponent Calculation:

```
exponent <- log(100)/log(MaxScoreEvents)
```

#### Generate  the scores:

```
df1$Score <- apply(as.matrix(events^exponent),1,FUN = function(x) {
  if (x > 100) {
    result <- 100
  }
  else if (x < 0) {
    result <- 0
  }
  else {
    result <- x
  }
  return(ceiling(result))
})

df1
```

#### Resulting Data Frame:

```
   userid events Score
1      a1      0     0
2      a2      0     0
3      a3      0     0
4      a4      0     0
5     a11      0     0
6     a12      0     0
7     a13      0     0
8     a14      0     0
9      u2      0     0
10  wtf42      0     0
11   ub40      0     0
12    foo      0     0
13    bar      1     1
14    baz      2   100
15   blue      3   100
16    bop      2   100
17    bob      3   100
18   boop      6   100
19   beep    122   100
20    mee     13   100
21      r      1     1
```

Under the assumption that your data is larger and has more event categories, the score won't snap to 100 so quickly, it is also a function of the threshold.

I would rely more on the data to define the parameters, threshold in this case.

If you have prior data as to what users really did whatever it is your score assess you can perform supervised learning, set the threshold @ wherever the ratio is over 50% for example. Or If the graph of events to probability of ‘success’ looks like the cumulative probability function of a normal distribution, I’d set threshold @ wherever it hits 45 degrees (For the first time).

You could also use logistic regression if you have prior data but instead of a Logit function ingesting the output of regression, use the number as your score. You can normalize it to be within 0-100.

It’s not always easy to write a Data Science question. I made many assumptions as to what you are looking for, hope this is the general direction.

Comment: I really like this answer and goes into the direction of what I'm also trying to build. In general, could you provide some pointers as to what techniques to learn in order to piece together such a scoring function? I know it's obviously related to statistics, but what exactly?